# case expression in sql to print the required text with prompt of user

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

Write a query to accept a number input between 1-3, if the user enters 1 the output has to be printed as "Yes",  if the user enters 2 the output has to be printed as "No",  if the user enters 3 the output has to be printed as "Maybe". If the user enters anything else apart from 1,2 or 3 the output should be printed is "Wrong"

```
select &expr   
CASE expr WHEN expr=1 then 'YES'
             WHEN expr=2 then 'NO'
             WHEN expr=3 then 'maybe'
             ELSE 'Wrong'
             END "OUTPUT" 
    from dual;
```

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) One good start is to ask a question....

Comment: @EricBrandt well can you help me

Comment: Apparently, no, I cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 
  CASE q'[&expr]'
    WHEN '1' then 'YES'
    WHEN '2' then 'NO'
    WHEN '3' then 'maybe'
    ELSE 'Wrong'
  END "OUTPUT" 
from dual;
```

or

```
select 
  decode(q'[&expr]'
           ,'1','YES'
           ,'2','NO'
           ,'3','maybe'
           ,'Wrong'
        )
  AS OUTPUT
from dual;
```